# Reuse a 2sxc DNN module twice with different content in each one

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Hi I am trying to use the '_Content - Title only.cshtml' module template for a text heading on my dnn page but wish to use multiple times on same page. Problem is once I select dnn option 'make a copy' and edit text it changes text for each instance of the 'title only' module? I know I can duplicate the '_Content - Title only.cshtml' Razor file but I hoped there might be an easier solution? Thx, Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the problem lies within the DNN copy functionality. It only copies the module "wrapper" but this wrapper still points to the same data - so editing it will edit the shared content-item.

Basically you just want to add another content module (not copy, add), and everything works.

Comment: Thx, yes I troubleshooted my way to this same conclusion and have been fine to add 2 instances of the same module since. Cheers, Denis